# Is it always possible to algebraically express a function defined by a set of rules?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Let's say you have an arbitrary function defined by a set of rules such that for example:

**Domain** $\hspace{9mm}$     **Range**

$\hspace{5mm}$ 1 $\hspace{23mm}$  2

$\hspace{5mm}$ 2 $\hspace{23mm}$  2

$\hspace{5mm}$ 3 $\hspace{23mm}$  2

$\hspace{5mm}$ 4 $\hspace{23mm}$  17

$\hspace{5mm}$ 5 $\hspace{23mm}$  0

$\hspace{5mm}$ 11 $\hspace{20mm}$  2435

...which can also include conditions such as $x > a$, etc...

Could you always express such a function algebraically, no matter how complex it is?

**How would you prove it?**

My intuition says you could, but I have no idea how to prove it.

Comment: See [polynomial interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation)

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, thank you, that's what I was looking for.